# Append two new columns to datframe using values from existing column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Say, I have a data frame which looks like.

```
 df.head()
    ID  col1    col2    col3    col4    type
    1   146       91      Rp    Rp-203  ex
    1   146      314      Rp    Rp-203  trans
    1   603       91      Rp    Rp-203  CDS
    1   910       81      Rp    Rp-203  CDS
    1   910       81      Rp    Rp-203  ex
    1   202      825      Rp    Rp-203  CDS
    1   202      837      Rp    Rp-203  ex
    1   200      314      Rp    Rp-203  ex
```

From the above data frame, I want to generate data frames. The data frame is based on the condition if the `type` column is equal to `ex`. In addition to that, the new data frame should have two additional columns with values separated with comma based on the `col1` and `col2`.

I want to generate two columns `col5` and `col6` using the values from `col1` and `col2` for each value in `col4` and `type` columns. 
That is, I want to group by on the column `col3` for values (`ex`) in the column `type`.

In the end, I am aiming to have data frames as,

```
ID  col1    col2    col3    col4    ex_start    ex_end
1   146     314     Rp      Rp-203  091,081,837 910,202,200
```

I have tried the follwoing solution,

```
df2 = df.loc[df['type']=='ex', ['col3','col1', 'col2',]].groupby(['col3']).agg(
        lambda x: ','.join([str(y) for y in x]))
```

However, my solution is capturing from the first value of the `col1` as `ex_start` first value. But I need the `col2` value as the first value in the `ex_start` column of `df2`. And `col1` value as the first value of `ex_end` column in `df2` and so on. 
And the column `col1` and `col2` in `df2`, should take the values from `df` columns `col1` and `col2` if the column `type` is equal to `trans`.

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain more about `col1` and `col2` in output?

Comment: @jezrael In the output, I need the values from `col1` and `col2` from `df`, in my `df2 `if the column `type` is equal to `trans`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter only ex rows by type
df3 = df[df['type']=='ex'].copy()

#shift values per groups from list
df3['s'] = df3.groupby(['ID','col3', 'col4'])['col2'].shift()
#removed NaNs rows per start and convert values to int and strings
df3 = df3.dropna(subset=['s']).assign(ex_start = lambda x: x['s'].astype(int).astype(str),
                                      ex_end = lambda x: x['col1'].astype(str))
print (df3)
   ID  col1  col2 col3    col4 type      s ex_start ex_end
4   1   910    81   Rp  Rp-203   ex   91.0       91    910
6   1   202   837   Rp  Rp-203   ex   81.0       81    202
7   1   200   314   Rp  Rp-203   ex  837.0      837    200

#then aggregate join
df4 = df3.groupby(['ID','col3', 'col4'])['ex_start','ex_end'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
print (df4)
   ID col3    col4   ex_start       ex_end
0   1   Rp  Rp-203  91,81,837  910,202,200

#filter by trans first rows per groups
df5 = df[df['type']=='trans'].drop_duplicates(['ID','col3', 'col4']).drop('type', 1)
print (df5)
   ID  col1  col2 col3    col4
1   1   146   314   Rp  Rp-203

#and add df5
df = df5.merge(df4)
print (df)
   ID  col1  col2 col3    col4   ex_start       ex_end
0   1   146   314   Rp  Rp-203  91,81,837  910,202,200
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I need `col1` and `col2` in the new dataframe.  I just updated my question.

Comment: @user1017373 - Answer was edited. But in your sample data is only one group, so not sure how are defined another groups an if really need grouping by `['ID','col3', 'col4']`

Comment: Thanks, other groups are in the same manner. They have a different ID, col3 and col4 values. I will test your solution on my big data frame and let you know

Comment: @user1017373 - Ok, so test with real data and if something wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach with groupby and a function to process

```py
def join(group):
    ex = group[["col1", "col2"]].copy().values
    row = group.iloc[0]
    row[["col1", "col2"]] = (ex[0,0], ex[-1,1])
    row["ex_start"] = ",".join(ex[1:,0].astype(str))
    row["ex_end"] = ",".join(ex[:-1,1].astype(str))

    return row

df.groupby("type").apply(join)
```

to get row of ex only you can do

```py
df.groupby("type").apply(join).loc[["ex"]]
```

**Output**

```
ID  col1    col2    col3    col4    type    ex_start    ex_end
type                                
CDS 1   603 825 Rp  Rp-203  CDS 910,202 91,81
ex  1   146 314 Rp  Rp-203  ex  910,202,200 91,81,837
trans   1   146 314 Rp  Rp-203  trans
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it is throwing the following error: 
`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int64 found`

Comment: corrected, in my case cols where string, you need to change them to string for join to work

Comment: Thank you still there is error, When I try this: `df.groupby("type").get_group("ex").apply(join)` I get the following error:
`KeyError: ("None of [['col1', 'col2']] are in the [index]", 'occurred at index ID')`

Comment: ya, its not workin ```df.groupby("type").apply(join).loc[["ex"]]``` use this instead